# netlogo convert string to numbers within nested lists

Tags: netlogo

I am transferring between NetLogo and igraph (in R). Some of the information returned from igraph is 2-level nested lists of strings. Typical example looks like:

```
[ ["1" "2" "3"] ["4"] ]
```

I want to convert the internal strings into numbers, while retaining the list structure. So the example would become:

```
[ [1 2 3] [4] ]
```

I am guessing I need a combination of `map` and `read-from-string` (and perhaps other list manipulation like `lput` and `foreach` due to the nesting), but I just can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, map each list to a mapped list with only int values.
Try the following:

```
show map [ map [ read-from-string ? ] ?] [ ["1" "2" "3"] ["4"] ]
```

Comment: thanks, I will go and code it up for the real example and see how i go

Comment: You actually don't need the square brackets around the `read-from-string`. You can just do `map [ map read-from-string ?] ...`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here is a version that can convert an arbitrary number of nested levels:

```
to-report read-from-list [ x ]
  report ifelse-value is-list? x
    [ map read-from-list x ] 
    [ read-from-string x ]
end
```

Example:

```
observer> print read-from-list [ ["1" "2" "3" ] ["4" [ "5" "6" ] ] ]
[[1 2 3] [4 [5 6]]]
```